# kubernetes lifecycle commands not running

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have been trying to get prestop to run a script before the pod terminates (to prolong the termination until the current job has finished), but command doesn't seem to be executing the commands. I've temporarily added an echo command, which i would expect to see in kubectl logs for the pod, i can't see this either.

This is part of the (otherwise working) deployment spec:

```
      containers:
        - name: file-blast-app
          image:  my_image:stuff
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["echo","PRE STOP!"]
```

Does anyone know why this would not be working and if i'm correct to expect the logs from hook in kubectl logs for the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to mention the shell through which you want this command to be executed.

Try using the following in your YAML.

```
  containers:
    - name: file-blast-app
      image:  my_image:stuff
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh","-c","echo PRE STOP!"]
```

Also, one thing to note is that a preStop hook only gets executed when a pod is terminated, and not when it is completed. You can read more on this [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55807).

You can also refer to the K8S official documentation for lifecycle hooks [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I was previously running a script calling the shell in that way, and that wasn't running either. Im using KEDA for scaling, so KEDA using its own custom metrics api is spinning down surplus pods, i can see 'Terminating' and the terminationGracePeriodSeconds is taking effect. I dont get any logs about failed lifecycle hooks in describe either.

Comment: @HappyMachine There are a couple of things you can do to debug. Use all available hooks and program then to echo commands during full lifecycle, that should give a clearer picture at the startup itself. Your YAML declaration is fine. Also, if you can, try running a separate cluster as Minikube, and try the 'kubectl delete' command and check if that's generating an output with the same approach or not. I hope KEDA is not consuming the preStop hook command output and not displaying it as stdout.

Comment: Hey Abhinav, this is the docs that mention leveraging that lifecycle method (with not much detail of how!) https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/scaling-deployments/ I assume that means KEDA isn’t intercepting, but I don’t get that echo log anywhere and even describe doesn’t show it failing or any related information

Comment: @HappyMachine yes! I did go through that documentation and it's incomplete. I'd suggest you open an issue on their GitHub page, since this external tool is managing you cluster. Did you try testing this without KEDA?